# awk/sed - generate an error if 2nd address of range is missing

Tags: awk, sed

We are currently using sed to filter output of regression runs. Sometimes we have a filter that looks like this:

```
/copyright/,/end copyright/d
```

If that `end copyright` is ever missing, the rest of the file is deleted. I'm wondering if there's some way to generate an error for this? awk would also be okay to use. I don't really want to add code that reads the file line by line and issues an error if it hits EOF.

```
here's a string
copyright
2016 jan 15
end copyright
date 2016 jan 5 time 15:36
last one
```

I'd like to get an error if `end copyright` is missing. The real filter also would replace the date line with DATE, so it's more that just ripping out the copyright.

Comment: That code DOES read the file line by line and how could it know if the end regexp was missing before it hits EOF without seeing it?

Comment: yes, I understand that. I'd just like an error if it hits the EOF without finding the closing range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* persuade sed to generate an error if you reach end of input (i.e. see address `$`) between your start and end, but it won't be a very helpful message:

```sed
/copyright/,/end copyright/{
$s//\1/  # here
d
}
```

This will error if `end copyright` is missing or on the last line, with an exit status of 1 and the helpful message:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

If you're using this in a makefile, you might want to `echo` a helpful message first, or (better) to wrap this in something that catches the error and produces a more useful one.

I tested this with GNU sed; though if you are using GNU sed, you could more easily use its useful extension:

> - ### `q` [EXIT-CODE]
>
>   This command only accepts a single address.
>
>   Exit 'sed' without processing any more commands or input.  Note
>      that the current pattern space is printed if auto-print is not
>      disabled with the `-n` options.  The ability to return an exit code
>      from the 'sed' script is a GNU 'sed' extension.
> - ### `Q` [EXIT-CODE]
>
>   This command only accepts a single address.
>
>   This command is the same as '`q`', but will not print the contents of
>      pattern space.  Like '`q`', it provides the ability to return an exit
>      code to the caller.

So you could simply write

```
/copyright/,/end copyright/{
$Q 42
d
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, of course - `d` starts the next cycle.  I originally had `$Q` first, but changed it without testing.  Edited and tested: `sed -f ./40727074.sed 40727074.data; echo $?` now gives `here's a string↵42`, where `↵` is a newline.

Comment: yes. this works and there's no loop that I have to write. I was trying to use the Q command, but couldn't get the order correct. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

With sed you can build a loop:

```
sed -e '/copyright/{:a;/end copyright/d;N;ba;};' file
```

`:a` defines the label "a"
`/copyright end/d` deletes the pattern space, only when "end copyright" matches
`N` appends the next line to the pattern space
`ba` jumps to the label "a"

Note that `d` ends the loop.

In this way you can avoid to delete the text until the end.

---

If you don't want the text to be displayed at all and prefer an error message when a "copyright" block stays unclosed, you obviously need to wait the end of the file. You can do it with sed too storing all the lines in the buffer space until the end:

```
sed -n -e '/copyright/{:a;/end copyright/d;${c\ERROR MESSAGE
;};N;ba;};H;${g;p};' file
```

`H` appends the current line to the buffer space
`g` put the content of the buffer space to the pattern space

The file content is only displayed once the last line reached with `${g;p}` otherwise when the closing "end copyright" is missing, the current line is changed in the error message with `${c\ERROR MESSAGE\n;}` inside the loop.

This way you can test what returns sed before redirecting it to whatever you want.

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation about how this works and why it is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Never use range expressions `/start/,/end/` as they make trivial code very slightly briefer but require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when you have the tiniest requirements change. Always use a flag instead. Note that since sed doesn't support variables, it doesn't support flag variables, and so you shouldn't be using sed you should be using awk instead.

In this case your original code would be:

```
awk '/copyright/{f=1} !f; /end copyright/{f=0}' file
```

And your modified code would be:

```
awk '/copyright/{f=1} !f; /end copyright/{f=0} END{if (f) print "Missing end copyright"}' file
```

The above is obviously untested since you didn't provide any sample input/output we could test a potential solution against.